# Generar/Guardar PDF con React y Strapi

Tags: reactjs, pdf

En el momento en el que un cliente realice un agendamiento, este debe recibir un correo con un PDF adjuntado donde figuren los datos tanto del cliente como de la propiedad agendada.

Necesito que el cliente, al momento de clickear el botón, se me genere y guarde ese PDF en una carpeta y a su vez poder adjuntarlo y enviarlo.

He intentado react-pdf y no se me da.

Al inicio coloco unas variables manuales, pero estas deberían ser llamadas desde Strapi, pero lo que me preocupa en este momento, es generar dicho PDF.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import {Row, Col, Label} from 'reactstrap';
// import 'react-pdf/dist/Page/AnnotationLayer.css';
class PDF extends Component {
  state = {
    numPages: null,
    pageNumber: 1,
    name: "Nombre y Apellido",
    rut: 262330770,
    to: "mail@example.com",
    image: "Imagen",
    type: "Casa/Departamento",
    address: "Dirección",
    uf: 10000,
    meters: 100,
    terraza: 150,
    rooms: 3,
    baths: 2
  }

  onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => {
    this.setState({ numPages });
  }

  render() {
    const { pageNumber, numPages, file, name, rut, to, image, type, address, uf, meters, terraza, rooms, baths } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="main">
        <section className="default-section">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-12 text-center">
                <Document file="somefile.pdf" onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
                  <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
                </Document>
                <p>Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 col-md-12 text-center">
                <br/>
                <img src={require('../../assets/images/mail/logo-booking.png')}/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 col-md-12 text-center">
                <h6>{name} | RUT: {rut} | Correo: {to}</h6>
              </div>
              <div className="container">
                <hr/>
                <Row>
                  <Col lg="8" offset-lg="2">
                    <h4>Orden de visita por la siguiente propiedad</h4>
                    <br/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xl="6" lg="6" md="6">
                    <h4>{image}</h4>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xl="6" lg="6" md="6">
                    <div className="bordered-box">
                      <h4>UF: {uf}</h4>
                      <label>Tipo de propiedad</label>
                      <p style={{textTransform: "capitalize"}}>{type}</p>
                      <label>Dirección referencial</label>
                      <p style={{textTransform: "capitalize"}}>{address}</p>
                      <label>Metros Construidos</label>
                      <p>{meters} m<sup>2</sup></p>
                      <label>Terraza</label>
                      <p>{terraza} m<sup>2</sup></p>
                      <Label>Dormitorios</Label>
                      <p>{rooms}</p>
                      <Label>Baños</Label>
                      <p>{baths}</p>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <hr/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default PDF;
```

Answer (score 1):

creo que estas errado en la forma de crear los pdf....

te muestro un ejemplo como yo lo hice, aunque rudimentario... asi deberia ser la logica...

```
import React from 'react';
import { Page, Text, View, Document, PDFViewer, Image } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import moment from 'moment';

const { currentUser, cart } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state'));
const address = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('addrs'));

const fecha = moment();
const table = (
    <View style={{margin: '10, 35', width: '90%' }}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', fontSize: 9, border: 1, backgroundColor: '#A9D0F5' }}>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '4%',}}>#</Text>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '22%',}}>Codigo</Text>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '40%',}}>Descripción</Text>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '10%',}}>Cantidad</Text>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '12%', textAlign: 'right'}}>Precio</Text>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '12%', textAlign: 'right'}}>Total</Text>
        </View>
        {cart.items.map((e, i) => (
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', fontSize: 9, }} key={i}>
                <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '4%',}}>{i+1}</Text>
                <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '22%',}}>{e.product.code}</Text>
                <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '40%', textAlign: 'justify'}}>{(e.product.name)}</Text>
                <Text style={{margin: '1, 5, ', padding: '1, 5', width: '10%',}}>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{e.quantity}</Text>
                <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '12%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{`$ ${(e.product.price).toFixed(2)}`}</Text>
                <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '12%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{`$ ${(e.product.price * e.quantity).toFixed(2)}`}</Text>
            </View>
        ))}
    </View>
);

const totales = (
    <View style={{marginLeft: 40, border: 1, width: 150}}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', fontSize: 10, borderBottom: 1}}>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '50%', borderRight: 1}}>SUBTOTAL</Text>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{`$ ${(cart.subtotal).toFixed(2)}`}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', fontSize: 10, borderBottom: 1}}>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '50%', borderRight: 1}}>ITBMS</Text>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{`$ ${(cart.itmbs).toFixed(2)}`}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', fontSize: 10, borderBottom: 1}}>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '50%', borderRight: 1}}>ENVIO</Text>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{`$ ${(0.00).toFixed(2)}`}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', fontSize: 10}}>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '50%', borderRight: 1}}>TOTAL</Text>
            <Text style={{margin: '1, 5', padding: '1, 5', width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{`$ ${(cart.total).toFixed(2)}`}</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
);


export default function Quote() {

    return (
        <PDFViewer height="100%" width="100%">
            <Document>
                <Page size="LETTER" >
                    <Image src="images/header.png" style={{width: '100%'}}/>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 12, marginTop: -21, marginRight: 50, textAlign: 'right'}}>{`C-${currentUser.id.padStart(5, '0')}`}</Text>
                    <View style={{fontSize: 10, margin: '5, 40'}}>
                        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                            <View style={{width: '50%', padding: '5, 15'}}>
                                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                    <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%',}}>N° CLIENTE:</Text>
                                    <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{currentUser.id.padStart(6, '0')}</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                    <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%',}}>NOMBRE:</Text>
                                    <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{`${currentUser.first_name.toUpperCase()} ${currentUser.last_name.toUpperCase()}`}</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={{border: 1, padding: 4}}>
                                    <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5 }}>DATOS DE FACTURACIÓN</Text>
                                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', fontSize: 9}}>
                                        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%',}}>Responsable:</Text>
                                        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{address && address.responsable}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', fontSize: 9}}>
                                        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%',}}>Telefono:</Text>
                                        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{address && address.phone}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', fontSize: 9}}>
                                        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%',}}>Dirección:</Text>
                                        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{address && address.address}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{width: '50%', padding: '5, 15'}}>
                                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                    <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%',}}>FECHA:</Text>
                                    <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{fecha.format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                    <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%',}}>VALIDEZ:</Text>
                                    <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{fecha.add('months', 1).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={{border: 1, padding: 4}}>
                                    <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5}}>DATOS DE ENTREGA</Text>
                                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', fontSize: 9}}>
                                        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%',}}>Responsable:</Text>
                                        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{address && address.responsable}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', fontSize: 9}}>
                                        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%',}}>Telefono:</Text>
                                        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{address && address.phone}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', fontSize: 9}}>
                                        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%'}}>Dirección:</Text>
                                        <Text style={{paddingBottom: 5, width: '50%', textAlign: 'right'}}>{address && address.address}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        {table}
                    </View>
                    <View style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 105, left: 405, right: 0, }}>
                        {totales}
                    </View>
                    <Image src="images/footer.png" style={{width: '100%', position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }}/>
                </Page>
                <Page size="LETTER">
                    <Image src="images/condiciones.png" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} />
                </Page>
            </Document>
        </PDFViewer>
    );
};
```

Comment: puedes cambiar las etiquetas style por classNames creados en este documento con StyleSheet